# how to udpate using patch powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, updatelistitems, powerapp, update

How to update using patch in SharePoint list from edit form?

Using below patch function. but, its creating new record every time.

```
Patch(test, Defaults('test'),
  {
    ReasonforLateSubmission: DataCardValue201_2.Text,
    WorkDescription: DataCardValue202_2.Text,
    OtherBusinessJustification: DataCardValue206_2.Text,
    DetailedWorkDescription: DataCardValue203_2.Text,
    WorkRequestJustification: DataCardValue204_2.Text,
    Title: DataCardValue210_2.Text

  }
);
```

Comment: You need to pass ID for update operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `ID` of list item as a `BaseRecord` for update operation.

**Syntax**:

```
Patch( DataSource, BaseRecord, ChangeRecord1 [, ChangeRecord2, … ])
```

> - `DataSource` – Required. The data source that contains the record that you want to modify or will contain the record that you want to create.
> - `BaseRecord` – Required. The record to modify or create. If the record came from a data source, the record is found and modified. If the result of **[Defaults](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-defaults)** is used, a record is created.
> - `ChangeRecord(s)` – Required. One or more records that contain properties to modify in the BaseRecord. Change records are processed in order from the beginning of the argument list to the end, with later property values overriding earlier ones.

**Source**: [Patch - Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch#syntax).

Also, check the examples given at [Patch - Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch#examples).

OR the excellant video tutorial given at: [PowerApps Patch Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gX5q_V3U8-s).

Comment: i am navigating to edit form gallery gallary.selected value

Comment: thank you its done

Comment: Great. glad it worked for you.